# IsEmpty() throws a runtime error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

All i am trying to get is the count right before an empty cell in the following code:

```
Dim l As Long
    Dim r As Long
    For l = 0 To 65866

    If IsEmpty(wb.Worksheets("Fund Position(URIL)").Range("A1")) Then
       Exit For
    Else
      r = r + 1
   End If
    Next l

    MsgBox r
```

The above code throws me an `Automation error` with a `Runtime error : -2147221080 (800401a8)` when it executes the `if` statement.

Please help!

**Update:**

I changed

`If IsEmpty(wb.Worksheets("Fund Position(URIL)").Range("A1")) Then`

to:

```
If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("Fund Position(URIL)").Range("A1")) Then
```

and it worked. Could someone explain me why is that?

Comment: I guess you are trying to find the last row in Col A which has data? If yes, then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find the first blank row in Col A.

Comment: first blank row can mean two things... Lets say `A1-A10` has data then `A11` is the blank cell that you want. Another scenarion. `A1-A5` has data and then A7-A10 has data. In this scenario do you want `A6` or `A11`

Comment: In the latter scenario, where an empty cell occurs between two ranges of non-empty cell. That is my scenario. Hence, i would want A6.

Comment: You cannot keep `.Range("A1")` constant? Else how will you find which row is empty? See the answer that I posted

Comment: I changed my code for simplicity. Originally, it checks cells dynamically based on the value of `l` . I knew there was no error there so i made it simple by keeping range constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim l As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Fund Position(URIL)")

    For l = 1 To 65866
        With ws
            If IsEmpty(.Range("A" & l)) Then Exit For
        End With
    Next l

    MsgBox l
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but i accomplished it by replacing `Worksheets` with `Sheets` and it worked. I do not know the difference though.

Comment: But that is wrong. You cannot keep .Range("A1") constant. Else how will you find which row is empty?

Comment: I am sure it did. Nevertheless, you were helpful :)